# Function "Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator" not found

Tags: function, error-handling, part-of-speech

I have in the POS-Tagging process the problem that R sends an ERROR notification when running the function
`Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator`
Following is the error notification:
`"Error in Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator() : 
  could not find function "Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator"`
I already checked if all packages are installed and that is the case. Now i don't know what to do anymore.